# Redshift running sum

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, window-functions

I am facing issue in the redshift running sum functionality. here is my set up.

Table

```
create table test
    (   cal_year varchar(30),
        cal_month varchar(30),
        dept_id varchar(50),
        hc int

    );
```

dummy values:

```
insert into qs.patpall_test values( 2021, 1 , 111, 50);
insert into qs.patpall_test values( 2021,1 , 222, 30);
insert into qs.patpall_test values( 2021,1 , 333, -5);
insert into qs.patpall_test values(2021, 2 , 222, 10);
```

Basically, for the first month, it is number of head count(hc) and for the 2nd month it just says me number of hc added or decreased.

Now, I need running sum for each year, month and dept wise. Here is code for that.

```
drop table if EXISTS a;
create temp  table a as
select cal_year, cal_month, dept_id, sum_hc,
       sum(sum_hc) over (PARTITION BY cal_year ,dept_id
            ORDER BY cal_month rows unbounded preceding ) as running_hc
 from   (
        select cal_year, cal_month, dept_id,
           sum(hc) sum_hc
    from qs.patpall_test
    group by 1,2,3
        );
```

If I check the output of above query at aggregated level. It gives me incorrect result.

```
select cal_year, cal_month, sum(sum_hc), sum(running_hc)
from a
group by 1,2
```

Here is output I get.

| Cal_year | Cal Month | sum_hc | running_hc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | 1 | 75 | 75 |
| 2021 | 2 | 10 | 40 |

It did not count dept ids which are not present for the 2nd month.

However, I am actually looking for below output.

| Cal_year | Cal Month | sum_hc | running_hc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | 1 | 75 | 75 |
| 2021 | 2 | 10 | 85 |

There are few depat_ids present in the 1st month but do not present in the 2nd month. Because of this, they are not added in the 2nd month running sum. I am looking for hc as on that month by adding all above month's dept in running sum and also able to drill down at particular month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long research, it seems like the window function can not handle this type of dataset. I could solve this problem with the below steps.

1. Get the distinct department IDs and store in temp table
2. Add fake or dummy entry in each month for missing department Id with hc 0.
3. window function query will work fine.

This approach worked fine and I am able to proceed further.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest running the code directly against the original table:

```
select cal_year, cal_month, sum(hc) as this_month_hc,
       sum(sum(hc)) over (order by cal_year, cal_month
                          rows unbounded preceding
                         ) as running_hc
from qs.patpall_test
group by 1, 2;
```

I see no advantage to using the intermediate table for what you want.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=d5f199a5922b2c8c0247013840cb074f) is a db<>fiddle (which happens to use Postgres but this is all standard SQL).

Comment: Thanks for reply. This will work when I only need aggregated table. The end purpose is to have drill down functionality as well at report level. So, I need to keep track how dept ids are adding up every month. And at each month what is total hc department wise. So, here in this case, I have dept id in the first month but when I drill down from report, I should be able to see that in the 2nd month, these many hc are from dept - 111,222,333 etc.

Comment: @PallavPatel . . . You can use another query or table for that purpose.

Comment: I did not get your comment. Another query or table. You meant to develop ETL flow and maintain a separate table? If my understanding is right, then we will have the same issue over there because partition by function is not able to carry forward missing values. Please correct me if my understanding is not right.

Comment: @PallavPatel. . . Actually, I don't understand your comment.  This question is clearly about *aggregated* data and this returns the values described in the question, as the SQL Fiddle illustrates.  If you have a different question, ask a *new* question.  This question has been answered.